# SQL query to get the data grouped by weeks for the last 17 weeks

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, pivot

We are trying to group by week for last 17 weeks in SQL Server 2012.

**Input data**

```
 OrderDate  OrderValue
 ----------------------
  7/17/11       10
  7/24/11       20
  7/31/11       30
   8/7/11       40
```

SQL tried on it: I am not sure if it is heading into right direction.

```
Select  
    om.OrderDate, SUM(MOrderQty * MPrice) as OrderValue 
from 
    OrdMaster om 
inner join 
    OrdDetail od on om.SalesOrder = od.SalesOrder 
where
    om.OrderDate >= DATEADD(WEEK, -17,getdate()) 
group by 
    om.OrderDate
```

Output data:

```
OrderValue   7/17/11     7/24/11     7/31/11     8/7/11  8/14/11     8/21/11     8/28/11     9/4/11  9/11/11    9/18/11  9/25/11     10/2/11     10/9/11     10/16/11    10/23/11    10/30/11    11/6/11
```

Any help with this would be much appreciated ! Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I'll suggest that if you don't already have the following indexes on the two tables, consider adding them to support what we're getting ready to do and more.

```
--===== If you don't already have them, consider adding these indexes
 CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX By_OrderDate
     ON [dbo].OrdMaster([OrderDate])
INCLUDE ([SalesOrder])
;
 CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX By_SalesOrder
     ON dbo.OrdDetail([SalesOrder])
INCLUDE ([MOrderQty],[MPrice])
;
```

To make this all "auto-magical", we have to use a bit of dynamic SQL.  It's called a "Pre-Aggregated Dynamic CROSSTAB", which is faster than most PIVOT operators. It will keep you from having to touch the code every week and it's nasty fast.  I also took the liberty of adding a "Total" column.  Details are in the code.

I also use "tokenized" dynamic SQL just to make things easier to code.  It's not necessarily SQL Injection proof (have to use QUOTENAME a lot) but there's no chance of that here because of the datatypes being converted.

And, yes, this gives you the "horizontal format" that you were looking for.

```
--=======================================================================================
--      Builds and executes a high performance, pre-aggregated CROSS TAB that will
--      return the previous 17 weeks without having to adjust the code no matter
--      what today's date is. It also returns a total for the 17 weeks.
--
--      Note that if any give week has no sales, then you'll have bigger things to
--      worry about other than this code won't pick up that missing week. ;-) 
--      We could fix that but it's not worth it because it shouldn't ever happen.
--=======================================================================================
--===== If the pre-aggregate table already exists, drop it to make reruns in SSMS easier.
     IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#PreAgg','U') IS NOT NULL
        DROP TABLE #PreAgg
;
--===== Pre-aggregate the data into a working table.
     -- The right indexes will make this very fast and it greatly reduces the amount of
     -- work the CROSSTAB will have to do.
 SELECT  WeekDate       = CAST(DATEADD(dd,DATEDIFF(dd,-1,om.OrderDate)/7*7,-1) AS DATE)
        ,OrderValue     = SUM(od.MOrderQty * od.MPrice)
   INTO #PreAgg
   FROM dbo.OrdMaster om
   JOIN dbo.OrdDetail od ON om.SalesOrder = od.SalesOrder 
  WHERE om.OrderDate    >= DATEADD(WK,-17,DATEADD(dd,DATEDIFF(dd,-1,GETDATE())/7*7,-1))
    AND om.OrderDate    <  DATEADD(dd,DATEDIFF(dd,-1,GETDATE())/7*7,-1)
  GROUP BY DATEDIFF(dd,-1,om.OrderDate)/7*7
;
--===== Declare a place to build the dynamic SQL in.
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(8000)
;
--===== Create the dynamic SELECT list of the CROSSTAB from the preggregated table.
 SELECT @SQL  = ISNULL(@SQL+SPACE(8)+',','')
              + REPLACE(REPLACE(
                    '[<<WeekDate>>] = SUM(CASE WHEN WeekDate = "<<WeekDate>>" THEN OrderValue ELSE 0 END)
'               ,'"'           ,'''') --These are the other end of the replaces.
                ,'<<WeekDate>>',CONVERT(CHAR(8),WeekDate,1))
   FROM #PreAgg
  ORDER BY WeekDate
;
--===== Create the static parts of the dynamic CROSSTAB SQL and insert the dynamic part.
 SELECT @SQL = REPLACE('
 SELECT  <<@SQL>>        ,[Total]    = SUM(OrderValue)
   FROM #Preagg
;'      ,'<<@SQL>>',@SQL) --The other end of the replace
;
--===== Display the dynamic SQL for troubleshooting purposes.
     -- This can be commented out for production.
  PRINT @SQL
;
--===== Execute the dynamic SQL
   EXEC (@SQL)
;
```

Comment: Thanks for dynamic query. I  just tried Pivot  but it looks  far better than  Pivot. I have to  still analyze  this into  production system  then want to discuss on it.

Comment: It is clean code . when i am executing it gives me desired output. Important  thing  is   I am able to read it because the way  you commented  class apart. Thanks for writing  such a clean  code.

Comment: I'm quite late with my reply but thank you very much for the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Select datepart(week, om.OrderDate)),
SUM(MOrderQty * MPrice) as OrderValue 
from OrdMaster om 
inner join OrdDetail od 
        on om.SalesOrder = od.SalesOrder 
where om.OrderDate >= DATEADD(WEEK, -17,getdate()) 
group by datepart(week, om.OrderDate))
```

See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx).

Comment: I am trying on Production .

Comment: what is week (om.OrderDate) it is not working. throwing error Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 1
'week' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: i am trying to achieve 17 date column in horizontal

Comment: I tried same query on sql server 2012 . but it is throwing that 'week' is not recognized as built in function

Comment: Output is not desire one  .http://paste.ofcode.org/h64sgiY8ChasKQp6VFxyCk

Comment: Please check Output data column in my question . i need total 18 column using 2 column . in that, 17 column grouped by week